# How to filter with multiple keyword in Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to check logs for my app with Android Studio. But I need to filter with either of two keywords. I've tried this `(foo|bar)` but only first filter `foo` is working. How can I filter properly?

Android Studio Filter
[image: Android Studio Filter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you removes parentheses and spaces.

A correct regex based on the image you posted might be:

```
foo|okhttp
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use regex search.

1. check Regex.
2. add your Regex expression.

```
^(.*(foo|bar)).*$
```

[image]